# Is it possible to use powershell to change file Explorer views?

Tags: powershell, windows-7, windows-7-x64, explorer, ntfs

I have thousands of folders, with lots of files in them and I'd like to be able to programmatically change how the file Explorer shows them.  Using the regular file Explorer options like List, Detail, Small, Medium, Large Icons, etc.  I'd be basing the view style based on the contents found in the folders.  That part I can figure out.  What's eluding me is whether there's any sort of programming interface to tell explorer.exe how to change the view for a given pathname.

All of the folders are on local NTFS volumes and I have full ACL permissions to them and their contents.

I specifically don't want to change the system-wide defaults, or use parent-down inheritance or template.  Rather I want a folder-by-folder setting of the view style.  I know it's possible to do this from the Explorer itself

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR, Windows 7 does not contain that option for Explorer ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_features_removed_in_Windows_7), [MS answers forum](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/is-remember-each-folders-view-settings/633192ab-e435-48cd-8fcd-999e7195653c)):

> The Remember each folder's view settings option to set Explorer to persist or not persist folder views and icon sizes per folder has been removed

---

However, if you find any method that fits your needs, you can use ProcMon to see what registry keys/values are created when you modify settings thru UI, then write corresponding POSH code for other cases.